# Не работает парсер python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Всем привет. я делал парсер python и при выводе текста в консоль он пишет "None", как это можно исправить?

вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://ru.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("article", class_="js-article-item articleItem     ")

print(post)
```

Comment: print(page.status_code)  == 403

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в том, что использование в этом случае классов не эффективен, поэтому советую лучше использовать другие методы, например  ID или CSSselector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае классы использовать не нужно. Будет достаточно просто указать тег "article" в аргументах к методу `.find()`.

Исходный код будет выглядеть так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://ru.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("article")

print(post)
```